# I need help with a test class unit

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have the following trigger and I would need some help in creating the test class.

```
trigger listingLocationUpdate on pba__Listing__c (before insert, before update) {

    //Mantiene actualizado el picklist Location en base al lookup Location
    List<pba__Listing__c> listings = Trigger.new;
    Map<Id, pba__Listing__c> oldListings = null;
    if (!Trigger.isInsert) {
        oldListings = Trigger.oldMap;
    }

    for (pba__Listing__c listing : listings) {

        if (!Trigger.isInsert) {
            pba__Listing__c oldListing = oldListings.get(listing.Id);
            if (oldListing.Location__c == listing.Location__c) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (listing.Location__c == null) {
            listing.fm_Location__c = null;
            continue;
        }

        pba__Location__c l = [Select Name from pba__Location__c where Id =:listing.Location__c];
        if (l != null) {
            listing.fm_Location__c = l.Name;
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Please read about [ask] and then [edit] your question to include any attempts that you've made. We are here to help you solve problems, not write code for you. We have a [ton of examples here already](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-test+trigger) that you could use to get started. We'll be glad to help you if you get stuck.

Comment: unrelated to the question, consider moving your soql query outside of the loop. Triggers are batched together with 200 records and that will cause a soql limit exception.